# mkdir() full access and rights

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

i have a problem with the function mkdir()

i get that error message:
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Unable to access /user/$id

and do not understand why. i set the rights for this direction to 0777 on my server, means full access to create an direction for everyone. even in my php code is set it up to 0777. but it doesn#t work.

here is my code:

```
mkdir ( '/user/$id', 0777 );
```

that means it should create a subfolder into the directionsfolder named user. user is like i already said, 0777. the permission in php too. what am i doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Do you actually have a folder `/user` at the root of your filesystem?

Comment: use double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: hello, yes i created it on my desktop and dropped it into my filesystem. the folder is there. i even tried it with double quotes. that even doesn´t work. get the errormessage: 
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Unable to access /user/200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the root folder? You may not have access to add a directory /user.

Try changing the single quotes to double quotes:

```
mkdir ( "/user/$id", 0777 );
```

This will allow you to pass the variable value into the string, instead of using $id.

Comment: In your index file, can you put `die(__DIR__);` at the top? This will give the full path to the folder your file is in. For example `/home/subdomains/test/public_html`. You may only have access to test or public_html. Try pasting the full path into the mkdir function.